# Laravel 5.2 and angularJS token mismatch

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am developing a webapp with static files on one server and api on another. The front end is developed using angular and backend using laravel.

For `CSRF-TOKEN` fetching during the first load, within angular `run block` I have this code

```
if(!$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')){
    $http.get(API+'/csrf_token').success(function(d){
        $cookies.put('XSRF-TOKEN',d.XSRF_TOKEN);
        //$cookies.put('laravel-session',d.LARAVEL_ID);
        //$http.defaults.headers.common.X-CSRF-TOKEN = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
        //$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN']=$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'); 
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN']=d.XSRF_TOKEN; 
      });
```

The other way I have tried to get the same was using [this](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/angularjs-csrf-token-constant) way.

Also set `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` so that cookies be sent along with requests.

The route `/csrf_token` setup as

`Route::get("/csrf_token", function(){
    //return \Response::json("asd",200)->withCookie(cookie("XSRF-TOKEN",csrf_token()));
     return csrf_token(); //\Crypt::encrypt(csrf_token())
});`

All the ajax `POST` requests throw `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`.

Next I have sent the `csrf_token` parameter as `_token` attached with the post parameters, still the same problem.

Tried all the above, returning encrypted token from `/csrf_token`, but still same problem.

Repeated all the steps clearing the config:cache and composer dumpautoload in api server, but still same problem.

Reviewed config file ,some values -

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'encrypt' => false,
 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
 'secure' => false,
```

(These values seem to be okay)
Next reviewed Virtual config file for CORS configuration (inside directory tag)

```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.mydomain.com" #real domain not posted  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true'
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "2000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
```

Wasted hours googling.(frustrated). Need help.

NB: I couldn't find any more tutorial/answers similar to token mismatch problem netiher on stackoverflow nor on any other website that I havn't tried. Thanks.

Comment: Is it solved yet ?

Comment: Yes. Do you want me to post the answer?

Comment: thanks, I got it solved but you should post to help others